# DataFrame in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, dataframe

under sex column of my Dataframe are for each row mehrere elemente (female, female) or (male, famale) or normal ones (female). Now i want to count the number of male and female for each row. can you help me pls?

```
import collections
for female in df_fundinv['borrower_genders'][0]:
    collections.counter()
type(liste)
collections.Counter(liste)


0                 female
1         female, female
2                 female
3                 female
4                 female
               ...      
646828            female
646829            female
646830    female, female
646831    female, female
646832            female
Name: borrower_genders, Length: 646833, dtype: object

gender.values
männlich={}
for element in gender.values:
    try:
        'element'!= 'male'
    except:
        männlich.append(dict(zip(male, counts)))

männlich
        


Was ich erwarte:


                                                        male(neue Spalte)                    female(neue Sp

0                 female                                                                       1                      
1         female, female                                                                       2                    
2                 female                                                                       1
3                 female
4                 female
               ...      
646828            female                                 
646829            female
646830    female, female                                 2                                        2
646831    female, female
646832            female
Name: borrower_genders, Length: 646833, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please make your header pertinent to the question, instead of something vague, as it is now ("DataFrame in jupyter notebook"). Please consider renaming it to something like "How do I sum each row of a dataframe efficiently placing the results of the sum in a new column?"

Comment: `your_dataframe.isin({"female"}).sum(1)` should get you what you want.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).